# Пунктуация в предложении "Но нет — есть!"

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно написать фразу: "Но нет — есть!" или "Но — нет, есть!"? Смысл такой: я думала что этого больше нет, но "нет — есть".

Comment: Не могу понять, что же есть у вас на самом деле?

Answer (score 1):

1) Выбираем вариант: *Но нет — есть!*

В таком предложении можно сделать только одну паузу.

Пример: Но нет, есть еще порох в шоферских пороховницах. [Б. Ю. Поплавский. Аполлон Безобразов (1932)]

Однако с точки зрения семантики предложение не кажется удачным.

Вариант правки: *Но нет — оно существует!*

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант: *Я думала что этого больше нет, но нет — есть!*
Его невозможно понять, сбивает с толку повторяющееся *нет* ("нет, но нет"), сочетание *нет* и *есть* ("нет — есть"). В принципе, **после "но нет" может стоять запятая, тире или двоеточие**. Варианты исправления:

- Я думала, что этого больше не существует, но нет, оно существует!
- Я думала, что этого больше не существует, но нет — оно существует!
- Я думала, что этого больше не существует, но нет: оно существует!

Примеры:

> Я только так говорю ― хозяйственная, **но нет**, это я постряпать хозяйственная, а экономить я не умею, для этого не создана, я люблю, чтобы деньги не считать, чтобы по ветру летели деньги. [И. Грекова. На испытаниях (1967)]
>
> Вот бы рассказы писать на печке, **но нет** ― не писатель я! [Анатолий Кириллин. С собой не возьму // «Сибирские огни», 2012]
>
> Они росли из щели между брёвнами наката и, казалось, должны были висеть вниз головой, **но нет**: каждая поганка грациозно изгибала тоненькую свою ножку и подымала вверх серую колокольчатую шляпку. [И. Грекова. На испытаниях (1967)]